# AngularJS cannot route from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I am using angularJS routing like this

```
$routeProvider.
      when('/wall', {controller:DashboardCtrl, templateUrl:'/chutirghonta_repo/contentpanel/views/dashboard.html'}).
      when('/books', {controller:BooksCtrl, templateUrl:'/chutirghonta_repo/contentpanel/views/books.html'}).
      when('/tests', {controller:TestsCtrl, templateUrl:'/chutirghonta_repo/contentpanel/views/tests.html'}).
      when('/createbook', {controller:CreateBookCtrl, templateUrl:'/chutirghonta_repo/contentpanel/views/bookcreation.html'}).
      when('/createbookpage', {controller:CreateBookPageCtrl, templateUrl:'/chutirghonta_repo/contentpanel/views/bookpagecreation.html'}).
      otherwise({redirectTo:'/wall'});
      ;
```

Now, in one of my controllers, I have to redirect to a another route, so I am using

```
$scope.add = function(){
    window.location = "/testwebsite/contentpanel/#/createbook";
}
```

The above code does not work. It takes me back to the default route, which is

```
window.location = "/testwebsite/contentpanel/#/wall";
```

But, amazingly, the code below works and leads me to the desired page

```
$scope.add = function(){
    window.open("/testwebsite/contentpanel/#/createbook");
}
```

In my view layer, I have a html page with this code snippet

```
<a href="#" ng-click="add()" class="btn btn-primary">Add New Book</a>
```

**I am out of ideas. window.open works but window.location does not work.**

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
window.location = "/testwebsite/contentpanel/#/createbook";
```

use

```
$location.url('/createbook')
```

Comment: using `$location.url('createbook')` does not solve the issue. but changing the anchor to a button works

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

I changed

```
<a href="#" ng-click="add()" class="btn btn-primary">Add New Book</a>
```

to

```
<button ng-click="add()" class="btn btn-primary">Add New Book</button>
```

Also, as Arnaud Gueras mentioned,

it is better to use

```
$location.url('/createbook');
```

instead of

```
window.location = '/testwebsite/contentpanel/#/createbook';
```

because the $location.url specifies only the last part of the path, where as window.location specifies the whole path (which might change when my hosting changes)